# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online register new assembly

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I downloaded a free 30 day trail from Microsoft, I wanted to Register a new Assembly using Plugin Registration Tool. When I go to create new connection, for discovery URL what do I write?
my url is: https:// xxxx.crm.dynamics.com

my company has a Dynamics CRM On Premise and I was able to connect and register a new assembly but there url contains port number, e.g. http:// xxxxx:5555/Dev

maybe using Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online there is no way to register custom assemblies? please let me know if its true (provide a link) or please let me know how to connect to CRM Online

Thank you

Comment: I presume that whoever marked you down and declined to leave a comment did so because they perceive that this information is readily available..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You absolutely can register assemblies in CRM Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309620.aspx) (but they must be registered in Sandbox / Isolation Mode).

The URL you need is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg328127.aspx). If you've only recently provisioned your environment then it'll be Office 365 based and therefore I think this is the URL you need for the plug-in registration tool:  https://disco.crm.dynamics.com

Note that it is your login credentials that will help the platform determine which organisation you are trying to access and you will be prompted to select from a list of orgs that you have access to, once the discovery service has authenticated you.

[This blog entry](http://readybms.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/error-registering-plugin-with-crm.html) describes your same scenario.